# How do I refactor the modal into a separate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

Sorry, React developer newbie. I have a working React Class Component with a popup Modal. It displays when you click on a Item Card:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Card, Button, CardImg, CardTitle, CardText, CardGroup,
  CardSubtitle, CardBody, CardFooter, CardHeader, CardColumns, CardDeck
} from 'reactstrap';
import Config from 'config';
import { decompressToBase64, formatter } from './common.js'
import "./Item.css";
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const customStyles = {
    content: {
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        right: 'auto',
        bottom: 'auto',
        marginRight: '-50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    },
};

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

class FeaturedCards extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'React',
            apiData: [],
            isOpen: false
        };        
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        const token = JSON.parse(tokenString);

        let headers = new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token
        });

        const response = await fetch(Config.apiUrl + `/api/Items/GetFeaturedItems`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({ itemList: json });
    }   

    render() {
        const items = this.state.itemList;
        let subtitle;

        handleClick = handleClick.bind(this);
        closeModal = closeModal.bind(this);

        function handleClick() {
            this.setState({ isOpen: true });
        }

        function closeModal() {
            console.log('Clicked close button')
            this.setState({ isOpen: false });
        }        

        function afterOpenModal() {
            // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
            subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <CardGroup className="card-group-scroll">
                    {items && items.map(item =>
                        <>
                            <Card key={item.itemNumber} tag="a" onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                                <CardHeader tag="h3">Featured</CardHeader>
                                <CardImg top className="card-picture" src={"data:image/png;base64," + decompressToBase64(item.images[0]?.compressedImageData)} id={item.itemNumber + "Img"} alt={item.itemNumber} />
                                <CardBody className="card-body">
                                    <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.itemNumber}</CardTitle>
                                    <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.categoryName}</CardSubtitle>
                                    <CardText className="card-description">{item.itemDescription}</CardText>
                                </CardBody>
                                <CardFooter className="text-muted">{formatter.format(item.price)}</CardFooter>
                            </Card>
                            <Modal
                                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                                onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
                                onRequestClose={() => closeModal()}
                                style={customStyles}
                                contentLabel={item.itemNumber}>
                                    <h2 ref={(_subtitle) => (subtitle = _subtitle)}>Hello</h2>
                                    <button onClick={() => closeModal()}>close</button>
                                    <div>I am a modal</div>
                                    <form>
                                        <input />
                                        <button>tab navigation</button>
                                        <button>stays</button>
                                        <button>inside</button>
                                        <button>the modal</button>
                                    </form>
                            </Modal>
                        </>
                    )}                
                </CardGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default FeaturedCards;
```

I need to use this same modal in several different places. I need the modal to have access to the item I clicked on. How do I refactor the modal into a separate file?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My first attempt:

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./Item.css";
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const customStyles = {
    content: {
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        right: 'auto',
        bottom: 'auto',
        marginRight: '-50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    },
};

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

class ItemModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);               
    }

    render() {
        let subtitle;

        closeModal = closeModal.bind(this);

        function closeModal() {
            console.log('Clicked close button')
            this.setState({ isOpen: false });
        }        

        function afterOpenModal() {
            // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
            subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
        }

        return (
            <Modal
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
                onRequestClose={() => closeModal()}
                style={customStyles}
                contentLabel={this.props.item.itemNumber}>
                    <h2 ref={(_subtitle) => (subtitle = _subtitle)}>Hello</h2>
                    <button onClick={() => closeModal()}>close</button>
                    <div>I am a modal</div>
                    <form>
                        <input />
                        <button>tab navigation</button>
                        <button>stays</button>
                        <button>inside</button>
                        <button>the modal</button>
                    </form>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
export default ItemModal;
```

I call it from `FeaturedCards` like this `<ItemModal item = { item } />`

I get an error: `TypeError: this.state is null`. I can't seem to figure out how to read(Share) the state from `FeaturedCards`...

Comment: Just write a component like `MyModal` and use props to pass on needed data. Then render `<Modal ...>...</Modal>` in the render method. There's really no difference from your FeaturedCards. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: have you tried anything already?

Comment: @RST Yes, but I I keep messing up my modal popping up.

Comment: Better share what you did so people can check where the problem is.

Comment: @RST I updated my attempt.

Comment: `MyModal` doesn't have any state.

Comment: programming note: if you're already using a normal arrow function as event handler, you don't need that `bind` nonsense, just use `onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal()}` instead of the `onRequestClose={() => closeModal()}` you have right now. The whole point of an arrow function is that it preserves the `this` context at declare time. No need to declare functions over and over and over every time `render()` runs: just make them normal class functions so that you can call them with `this.functionNameHere()`

Comment: Don't post an "update" with a new slew of code, unless something historical happened (e.g. it's an answer, time has past, and the answer's solution requires different code for a newer version that came out after the original answer was written, while still needing to show the old code for older versions). Just edit your post to show the actual code _you_ are using that exhibits the problem you're facing, and structure your post's text to talk about that. Any code you had before is no longer relevant to your question, because it's not your code anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the very basic(with only open and close functionalities) example of how you can create a common modal (there could be other ways...).

```
class ItemModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);               
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                isOpen
                onRequestClose={this.props.onRequestClose}
                >
                  Sample content
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
export default ItemModal;
```

and this can be used like below.

```
class FeaturedCards extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };        
    }

    onRequestClose = () => {
      this.setState({isOpen: false});
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    }

    render() {
      const { isOpen } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}> open Modal</button>
              { isOpen ? <ItemModal onRequestClose={this.onRequestClose} /> : null }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default FeaturedCards;
```

Comment: Had to remove `this` in `onClick={this.handleClick}` and the same for `onRequestClose={this.onRequestClose}`. However it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Randy it’s because in your code you defined all these functions inside render method thus you don’t need ‘this’ over there. But when you define your methods as component members like in my example then you need to use ‘this’ to use them.